# Unable to get rid of timeout exception error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

After running my below script It crawls the first link successfully and fetch the `title` and `description` but when it comes to do the same for the next link I encounter `stale element reference:` in this line `data = [urljoin(link,item.get_attribute("href"))---`. How can I complete the operation without this error?

This is the script:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "http://urbantoronto.ca/database/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for items in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#project_list table tr[id^='project']"))):
    data = [urljoin(link,item.get_attribute("href")) for item in items.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href^='//urbantoronto']")]

    #I get stale "element reference" error exactly here pointing the above line

    for nlink in data:
        driver.get(nlink)
        sitem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.title")))
        title = sitem.text
        try:
            desc = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".project-description p"))).text
        except Exception: desc = ""
        print("Title: {}\nDescription: {}\n".format(title,desc))

driver.quit()
```

Comment: I guess this is because you defines the `sitem` **after** `driver.get(nlink)`. You should do this **before** navigating to next page. And also put `wait.until(EC.staleness_of(sitem))` just after `driver.get(nlink)`

Comment: See the edit sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is your outer loop. The 'items' that your iterating over all go stale as soon as you change pages, i.e., driver.get(nlink). That's why you were getting the StaleElementException on the second time through the loop at items.find_elements...  The reason it's timing out on 'sitem' is because elements only go stale when the DOM changes. If the DOM doesn't change, well, you could be waiting awhile for a stale element.

With that in mind, I suggest slightly different approach using BeautifulSoup. Selenium is great for javascript execution and all, but a little slow when it comes to parsing HTML, which is something you're doing for all of those table rows. So I suggest the following changes:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

link = "http://urbantoronto.ca/database/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# For readability
by_selector = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#project_list table tr[id^='project']")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(by_selector))

# Get HTML content
soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

# Find div containing project table
table = soup.find('div', {'id': 'project_list'})

# Find all the project rows
projects = table.find_all('tr', {'id': re.compile('^project\d+')})

# Create page links
links = ['http:' + x.find('a')['href'] for x in projects]

for nlink in links:

    driver.get(nlink)
    sitem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.title")))
    title = sitem.text
    try:
        desc = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".project-description p"))).text
    except Exception: desc = ""
    print("Title: {}\nDescription: {}\n".format(title,desc))

driver.quit()
```

**EDIT:** Here is a pure selenium solution:

```
link = "http://urbantoronto.ca/database/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# For readability
condition = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#project_list table tr[id^='project']")
tr = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(condition))

# Get links, this will take a few seconds with Selenium
selector = "a[href^='//urbantoronto']"
links = [x.find_element_by_css_selector(selector).get_attribute('href') for x in tr]

for nlink in links:

    driver.get(nlink)
    sitem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.title")))
    title = sitem.text
    try:
        desc = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".project-description p"))).text
    except Exception: desc = ""
    print("Title: {}\nDescription: {}\n".format(title,desc))

driver.quit()
```

And just to be clear, you need to extract the URLs before the loop to avoid the stale element issue you were having.

Comment: It does the job @T. Ray. +1 for this. However, I'm still sanguine to have any pure selenium solution.

Comment: Then pure selenium you shall have. See my updated answer.

Comment: I wish I coud upvote your solution several times. You made it. So, my defined nested loop was the culprit!! Thanks a lot.